# Without import the Angular Service to the module, can we use it?

Tags: angular

Without import the Angular Service to the module, can we use it?

```
providers: [ApiService,EmployeeService,DataService,MatDatepickerModule,StudentServiceService
  ,  { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
  { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DateFormats }],
})
```

here I have imported all the service classes. my question is 'Without import the Angular Service to the module, can we use it?'

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking about alternative ways to set up dependency injection with services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with Angular 6 + you can mark services line this

```
@Injectable({provideIn: 'root'})
class MyService {
...
}
```

then you dont need to provide them explicitly

Comment: core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HeaderComponent -> AuthService]:

Comment: import { ApiService ,Register,JwtResponse} from '../../shared';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
}

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you need to inject it where you are going to use it